# Using Devise in Rails4, how to allow users to only the edit their own comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm confused with how to use Devise's current_user helper in my views and controllers. Do I need to do a  migration to add user_id in my database tables? Do I need to do something with the sessions controller?

Here is my routes file:

```
 devise_for :users

  resources :groups, shallow: true do
      resources :ideas do
           resources :comments
      end
  end
```

Sign in / sign up etc. is working fine. I would like to allow users to edit only the ideas and comments, that they created.

Do I need to add in my applications controller a helper method, for example:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
```

Then, in theory, I should be able to do the following?

```
   <% if current_user %>
       <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_idea_path(@idea) %>
   <% end %>
```

And then I also need to I guess update my controller edit action with current_user? E.g. ?

```
    @comment = current_user.comment.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Devise is an authentication system whereas you need authorization logic to achieve that. See https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan gem. If you don't want using additional gem for that, you have to implement it yourself. Devise is only authentication system.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could use the current_user for simple authorisation logic. I will use cancancan, thanks again for all replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you are trying to do is:

```
  <% if current_user.id == @idea.user.id %>
       <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_idea_path(@idea) %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% if current_user.id == @idea.user.id %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_idea_path(@idea) %>
<% end %>
```

Would *kinda* work, but it is about as secure as an unlocked door. It doesn't explicitly prevent a user from going to `/idea/5/edit` and making those changes (even if they didn't create/own idea 5). As mentioned above: either use CanCan or roll your own solution in the controller on the :update method.

Comment: I agree with you that this is not secure at all but it is the problem that they was having. Security is a different animal all together